# Actualizar datos de un nav header menu desde un fragment en Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

soy nuevo en Stack, mi duda es la siguiente:
Quiero cambiar el texto de usuario y correo de un nav header desde un fragment.
Tengo una aplicación que al iniciar sesión pasa unos parametros al menuActivity y desde ahí actualizo los datos del nav header, ahí todo bien. Pero mi menu tiene un fragment donde también puedo actualizar los datos pero no logro que los actualice en el navheader. ¿Hay alguna forma de lograrlo?
Desde el activity actualizo el navheader de la siguiente forma:

**MenuActivity.java**

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    txtEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textViewPass);
    txtUser.setText(variables.vUsuario);
    txtEmail.setText(variables.vCorreo);
```

¿De qué forma puedo aplicar ese método en un fragment?
ya que no puedo utilizar (this) en un fragment y al navigationView.getHeaderView(0) me marca algún tipo de error nulo.

Gracias de antemano. Soy nuevo en esta parte de Android.

Comment: Cuando deseas obtener el contexto dentro de un fragment, puedes con getAplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Para ello debes crear un método en la `activity` y llamarlo desde el `fragmento` que tengas asociado a dicha `activity`:

**ActivityX**

```
public void changeNavHeaderData(){
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    txtEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textViewPass);
    txtUser.setText(variables.vUsuario);
    txtEmail.setText(variables.vCorreo);
}
```

**Fragment**

```
((ActivityX)getActivity()).changeNavHeaderData();
```

Aunque es recomendable setear el `activity` en el `onAttach` para evitar posible nullPointers:

```
    ActivityX activityX;

   @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activityX.changeNavHeaderData();
     }

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
            activityX = (Activity) context;
     }
```